# how to do exact match on multiple lines linux

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I want to print only the lines where interface Gigabitehternet has a description.  i used:

```
cat filter.txt | awk '/interface/ || /description/'
```

So as output of **filter.txt** i want to see the following.

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/26  
description test1  

interface GigabitEthernet0/27  
description test2  

interface GigabitEthernet0/28   
description test3  


interface GigabitEthernet0/29   
description test 4 


tst:~$ cat filter.txt
interface Port-channel1   
interface FastEthernet0   
interface GigabitEthernet0/1    
interface GigabitEthernet0/2   
interface GigabitEthernet0/3   
interface GigabitEthernet0/4   
interface GigabitEthernet0/5   
interface GigabitEthernet0/6   
interface GigabitEthernet0/7   
interface GigabitEthernet0/8   
interface GigabitEthernet0/9   
interface GigabitEthernet0/10   
interface GigabitEthernet0/11   
interface GigabitEthernet0/12   
interface GigabitEthernet0/13   
interface GigabitEthernet0/14   
interface GigabitEthernet0/15  
interface GigabitEthernet0/16   
interface GigabitEthernet0/17   
interface GigabitEthernet0/18   
 description test1    
interface GigabitEthernet0/19   
 description test2    
interface GigabitEthernet0/20    
interface GigabitEthernet0/21    
interface GigabitEthernet0/22    
interface GigabitEthernet0/23    
interface GigabitEthernet0/24   
interface GigabitEthernet0/25   
interface GigabitEthernet0/26   
 description test3   
interface GigabitEthernet0/27   
 description test4   
interface GigabitEthernet0/28   
 description test5    
interface GigabitEthernet0/29   
 description test6   
interface GigabitEthernet0/30
```

thanks for your help

Comment: Most `interface GigabitEthernet0` have no description in your desired output.

Answer (score 2):

```
#use sed
sed -n '/interface/h;/description/{s/^ //;H;x;p}' file.txt 
#use awk
awk '/interface/{s=$0;}/description/{$1=$1;print s RS $0 ;s="";}' file.txt 
#output:
interface GigabitEthernet0/18   
description test1    
interface GigabitEthernet0/19   
description test2    
interface GigabitEthernet0/26   
description test3   
interface GigabitEthernet0/27   
description test4   
interface GigabitEthernet0/28   
description test5    
interface GigabitEthernet0/29   
description test6
```

Comment: I think you can change your second command to:

`awk '/interface/{s=$0;}/ (description)/{print s RS $1;s="";}' ./file.txt`.

It will delete the blank before the `description` as questioner expected.

Comment: i don't understand

Comment: The is a space before the `(description)`.

Comment: In the output questioner wanted,There is no space before `description`.

Comment: sorry for the space, just leave the space as is from the filter.txt.

Comment: i see its almost good, im missing now only the rest of the description in the output.

Comment: awk '/interface/{s=$0;}/description/{print s RS $0;}' ./filter.txt                    its working now thanks